# FactoryGirl, has_one association and validation failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

These are 2 simple models:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :asset, :dependent => :destroy

  validates :asset, presence: true
end

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I'm trying to create a factory like this:

```
  factory :post do
    # fields...

    asset { FactoryGirl.create(:asset) }
  end

  factory :asset do
    # fields...

    post
  end
```

But, running the spec it enters a loop.

I've also tryied this:

```
  factory :post do
    # fields...

    before(:create) do |post, evaluator|
      FactoryGirl.create_list(:asset, 1, post: post)
    end
  end
```

But ended up in "Validation failed: Asset can't be blank".

How do I represent my situation?

Comment: Is there any reason you're setting `post` on `:asset` instead of the other way around? Seems weird since `Post` is the one requiring an `Asset` during creation.

Comment: Factory's associations stand for foreign_keys and not for has_one/has_many associations. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I solved this problem using after(:build) callback.

```
factory :post do
    # fields...
    after(:build) do |post|
      post.asset ||= FactoryGirl.build(:asset, :post => post)
    end
end

factory :asset do
    # fields...
    after(:build) do |asset|
      asset.post ||= FactoryGirl.build(:post, :asset => asset)
    end
end
```

By this way, the associated objects will be created before the owning class is saved, so validation pass.

Comment: other callbacks include `after(:create)` and `after(:stub)` which are mentioned at https://robots.thoughtbot.com/aint-no-calla-back-girl

Comment: @MichDart I couldn't see this working. I assigned it in build callback, printed in before create call back., object is not there. Is it updated?

Comment: @7H3IN5ID3R, first I couldn't get it working as well... Check that your validation does not include `_id` at the end. E.g, `validates :asset, presence: true` instead of `validates :asset_id, presence: true`.

Answer (score 2):

The validation is failing because when `FactoryGirl` creates a `Post`, an asset must be present. So in your `FactoryGirl` definitions you can create an `Asset` as part of creating a `Post`. Insert something like the `FactoryGirl post.rb` file:

```
asset { FactoryGirl.create(:asset) }
```

or

You can create an `Asset` as part of your `Post` declaration in your spec file such as the following:

```
asset = FactoryGirl.create(:asset)

FactoryGirl.create(:post, :asset => asset)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. I've updated the first post. But I'm still in trouble. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can preload a child association by passing it in as follows:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    asset { Asset.create! }
  end
end
```

(Better still, using the Asset factory to generate it's associated asset with details pre-set).

The other manual way would be to create a Asset via FactoryGirl.create(:asset), and passing it into the variable creation, i.e.:

```
asset = FactoryGirl.create(:asset)
post = FactoryGirl.create(:post, asset: asset)
```

Comment: Thanks, but does your solution create an asset with the same fields I've defined into my Asset factory?

Comment: If you want it to create an asset with the same fields defined in your asset factory: `asset { FactoryGirl.create(:asset) }`

Comment: Please take a look at the last update above... I still encounter errors

Comment: Does your Asset factory create a Post model? If so you'll end up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

the error `Validation failed: Asset can't be blank` is because it looks like you have the association backwards in your factories.

```
factory :post do
  # fields...
end
```

So when you create a `post` there is no `asset` so the validation fails. Try this

```
factory :post do
# fields...
  asset
end
```

Take a look at this [wiki page and the associations section](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md). It also explains the difference between `create` and `build` with associations

Comment: I've tried that solution, but didn't work. It creates a loop (I think). Have you tried on your own? thanks anyway